# Integrate this function with one variable depending on the other

Tags: probability, integration

Let $c$ be constant $> 0$.

$f_X(x) = \int_{0}^2 cxy dy$ for $0 \leq x \leq y$.

I don't know how to handle the case that x depends on y in this way.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. If $y$ is an upper bound on $x$, it can't also be the dummy integration variable.

Comment: Saying that $x\le y$ means that for a given x the integral is from x to y.  That is, $f_X(x)=  \int_x^2 cxydy= cx\int_x^2 ydy$.  (I just saw J.G.'s comment.  You can think of this as $cx\int_x^2 tdt$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming @user237327's reading of the question's intent is correct,$$f_X(x)=\frac12cx(4-x^2)\implies\frac1c=\int_0^2\frac12(4x-x^3)dx\implies c=\frac12.$$